# nginx: How do I make a rewrite (redirect) relative? (i.e. don't mess with the port number!)

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm using nginx 1.9.11 currently.  I have a situation where my application is served up from a dynamic port via a load balancer, but the port on the app itself is set.  It looks like this

```
Port [4000-4999] on load balancer -> instances of nginx all on port 80
```

I need to redirect `/myapp` to `/myapp/` without losing the port information.  But I don't know the port at the application level, because the apps are dynamically created and destroyed!

Here's the syntax of my rewrite rule:

```
rewrite ^/myapp /myapp/
```

What I get is:

```
http://example.com:4000/myapp  -> http://example.com/myapp   # no port 4000!
```

I can't hardcode the port...because there's a thousand possibilities, and they change all the time!  I need to stay on the same port, but I don't know what port we came in on.  How do I get nginx to leave the port alone?

---

**What I've tried already...**

In `http`, `server`, and `location` sections:

```
port_in_redirect off;
```

In the `server` section:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
```

Also in the `server` section as well:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_redirect off;
```

Answer (score 1):

Classic.  After two days of efforts I write up a nice Stack Overflow post, and immediately afterwards something occurs to me, I try it, and it works.

Here's how I solved the problem:  I changed the rewrite rule to look like this:

```
rewrite ^/myapp $http_host/myapp/
```

And it worked!